# cordovaプラグインはmonacaクラウドIDEのプレビュー上で動作しますか？

Tags: monaca, cordova

monacaクラウドIDEでcordova File Pluginを使ってファイル書き出しをしたいと考えています。
現在一時的にスマートフォンの実機を使用できない環境なのですが、IDEのpreview機能だけで動作させることはできますか？

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/development/monaca_ide/overview/#preview-team-panel

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
マニュアルに明記してあったのですね！
今度からよく確認します。

Comment: Androidのデバッグ環境でよければ「Genymotion」を使う手もあります。実機は不要です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monacaのライブプレビューでは動きません。

CordovaのプラグインはWebView(Webブラウザ)に無い機能を実現する為の物です。
AndroidやiOSのAPIを呼ぶことで実現されています。ブラウザで動かす事は想定していなかったり、そもそもブラウザの制限で実現不可能な機能であったりします。

別の言い方をすると、Webブラウザで実現可能な機能はCordovaプラグインとして用意する必要が無いという事です。
ただ、プラグインがプラットフォーム間の差異を吸収するという位置付けであればブラウザでも動くべきだと思いますし、将来は分かりませんね。

実機が用意出来無い場合はAndroid エミュレーターで[Monaca デバッガーを使う方法](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/debugger/installation/debugger_emulator/)もあります。（この場合はエミュレータの動作速度が問題になります。そこは別途調べて下さい）